# Get days in a particular month

Tags: java, date

How do I get days of a particular month using java.util.Calendar.
I have tried the code given below, but it gives me the days for the latest month and not the month I have given as input.
**I don't want to use a switch case.**
Can anyone please help?
Thanks in advance!

```
public static void main(String args[]) throws ParseException {

    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    int month = cal.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    int year = cal.get(Calendar.YEAR);


    if (month == 0) {
        month = 3;
        year = year-1;
    }

    String dateStart = "'" + (year) + "-" + (month) + "-1 00:00:00'";
    String dateEnd = "'" + (year) + "-" + (month) + "-" 
                            + cal.getMaximum(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
    dateEnd = dateEnd + " 23:59:59'";
    System.out.println("Start and End Date : " + dateStart + " : " + dateEnd);
}
```

Comment: You need to set the `MONTH` of the calendar as well as the `YEAR`. Else it uses the date/time of the instance creation

Comment: [For example](https://www.leveluplunch.com/java/examples/find-number-of-days-in-month/) - for my money, I'd be using the Date/Time API available in Java 8+

Comment: Also month is 0 for January and 11 for December, so dateStart and dateEnd should have (month+1).

Comment: @MadProgrammer i used the logic but i dont understand it can u please help

Comment: Use [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html). Do not use `Calendar` since that class had severe design problems and has been outdated for 10 years. Also don’t use 23:59:59 as the end. Use 00:00 on the 1st of the following month. The second you are missing could be crucial in some situations. Finally use a `DateTimeFormatter` for formatting date and time for output instead of concatenating a string yourself.

Comment: *get days of a particular month* I take it that you mean *how many days* there are in the month, the same as the day number of the month of the last day in the month. Not a list of all the days. Is this understanding correct, please?

Answer (score 3):

This is an example of how to get the days of a given `int month` and `int year` using `java.time`,
  **have a look at the comments**:

```
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.YearMonth;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.time.format.TextStyle;
import java.util.Locale;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.TreeSet;
import java.util.stream.IntStream;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int month = 1;
        int year = 2018;

        // create something that stores the days and keeps them sorted, preferably
        Set<LocalDate> allDaysOfGivenMonth = new TreeSet<LocalDate>();

        // stream the days from first to last day of the given month
        IntStream.rangeClosed(1, YearMonth.of(year, month).lengthOfMonth())
                .mapToObj(day -> LocalDate.of(year, month, day)) // map them to LocalDate objects
                .forEach(localDate -> allDaysOfGivenMonth.add(localDate)); // and store each of them

        // afterwards, just print them for a first glance...
        allDaysOfGivenMonth.forEach(localDate -> {
            System.out.println(localDate.format(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE) + " - " 
                    + localDate.getDayOfWeek()
                                .getDisplayName(TextStyle.FULL_STANDALONE, Locale.getDefault()));
        });
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

The existing answers seem complex or use legacy API.

### java.time

I recommend you avoid using the outdated `java.util` date/time API and do it using the [modern date/time API](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-date-time.html), `java.time`.

You only need this much logic:

```
LocalDate.of(year, month, 1)
         .datesUntil(YearMonth.of(year, month).plusMonths(1).atDay(1))
         .map(d -> d.getDayOfWeek().getDisplayName(TextStyle.FULL, Locale.ENGLISH))
         .forEach(System.out::println);
```

**Demo**:

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Test
        printAllWeekdaysOfYearMonth(2024, 2);
    }

    // Prints weekday name of all days of a given year and month in the system's timezone
    static void printAllWeekdaysOfYearMonth(int year, int month) {
        LocalDate.of(year, month, 1)
                .datesUntil(YearMonth.of(year, month).plusMonths(1).atDay(1))
                .map(d -> d.getDayOfWeek().getDisplayName(TextStyle.FULL, Locale.ENGLISH))
                .forEach(System.out::println);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
Thursday
Friday
...
...
...
Thursday
```

#### [Demo](https://ideone.com/LQ4xmn)

**Notes**:

1. [`LocalDate#datesUnti`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase%2F9%2Fdocs%2Fapi%2F%2F/java/time/LocalDate.html#datesUntil-java.time.LocalDate-) excludes the date passed to it as an argument; therefore, I have used the first day of the next month as the argument so that the stream can go until the last date of the given month.
2. Depending on what else, along with the weekday names, you want to print, you can change the [`Stream#map`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#map-java.util.function.Function-) in the above code e.g. if you want to display dates along with the weekday names, you can use `map(d -> d.toString() + " " + d.getDayOfWeek().getDisplayName(TextStyle.FULL, Locale.ENGLISH))`. 
   [Demo](https://ideone.com/Nuilad)
3. You can also use [`DateTimeFormatter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html) to get the same output as the one in the demos shown above.  [Demo1](https://ideone.com/vnqL0Q) | [Demo2](https://ideone.com/qyU3hJ)

**If you want just how many days are in the month**

Use either

```
    int daysCount = YearMonth.of(2024, 2).lengthOfMonth();
```

or still more human readable

```
    int daysCount = YearMonth.of(2024, Month.FEBRUARY).lengthOfMonth();
```

Output in both cases:

> 29

[**Demo**](https://ideone.com/t9SsfO)

Learn about the modern date-time API from **[Trail: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html)**

Answer (score 0):

i used this logic from the above comments but i dont understand the logic behind it can anyone explain me the logic for it

```
public static void main(String args[]) throws ParseException{

        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        int month = cal.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        int year = cal.get(Calendar.YEAR);


        if(month == 0){
            month = 6;
            year = year-1;
        }
        String dateStart = "'"+(year)+"-"+(month)+"-1 00:00:00'";
            cal.set(Calendar.MONTH, 5);
            cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 6);
            cal.set(Calendar.YEAR, 2019);
        String dateEnd = "'"+(year)+"-"+(month)+"-"+cal.getActualMaximum(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
        dateEnd = dateEnd+" 23:59:59'";
        System.out.println("Start and End Date : "+dateStart+" : "+dateEnd);
    }
```

Comment: You don’t want to understand how `Calendar` works. It would take you forever since it’s a very cumbersome class to work with with some indeed strange behaviours. Also it’s long outdated. You want to move on to java.time as shown in the other answers.

Answer (score 0):

## tl;dr

```java
YearMonth
.of( 2024 , Month.JANUARY )
.atDay( 1 )
.datesUntil( YearMonth.of( 2024 , Month.JANUARY ).plusMonths( 1 ).atDay( 1 ) )
.map( ( LocalDate localDate ) ->
        Interval.of(
                localDate.atStartOfDay( ZoneId.of( "Africa/Tunis" ) ).toInstant( ) ,
                localDate.plusDays( 1 ).atStartOfDay( ZoneId.of( "Africa/Tunis" ) ).toInstant( )
        )
)
.toList( )
.forEach( System.out :: println );
```

```
2023-12-31T23:00:00Z/2024-01-01T23:00:00Z
2024-01-01T23:00:00Z/2024-01-02T23:00:00Z
…
2024-01-29T23:00:00Z/2024-01-30T23:00:00Z
2024-01-30T23:00:00Z/2024-01-31T23:00:00Z
```

## *java.time*

### Avoid legacy date-time classes

The terribly flawed `Calendar` class was years ago supplanted by the modern *java.time* classes defined in JSR 310.

### `YearMonth`

To represent an entire month, use `YearMonth` class.

```
YearMonth yearMonth = YearMonth.of( 2024 , Month.JANUARY ) ;
```

### `LocalDate`

Get first day of that month.

```
LocalDate firstOfThatMonth = yearMonth.atDay( 1 ) ;
```

### `Stream < LocalDate >`

Get a stream of `LocalDate` objects, one for each day of the month.

```
Stream < LocalDate > datesOfMonthStream = firstOfThatMonth.datesUntil( yearMonth.plusMonths( 1 ).atDay( 1 ) );
```

### `List < Interval >`

You want collect the start and end moments of each date.

First of all, do not assume when the day starts and ends. The length of a day, and its start/end, vary by date by time zone. For example, in some zones, a particular day may start at 01:00 rather than the usual 00:00.

Also, track a span of time using the Half-Open approach rather than Fully-Closed. In Half-Open, the beginning is *inclusive* while the ending is *exclusive*. In your attempt at Fully-Closed, you are ignoring the final second of the day.

#### `org.threeten.extra.Interval`

You could define your own class, likely a record, to represent the span of each day. But do not bother — such a class has already been written, in the [*ThreeTen-Extra*](https://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) library. There you will find the [`Interval`](https://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org.threeten.extra/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html) class. That open-source library is led by the same man who invented the *java.time* classes, [Stephen Colebourne](https://github.com/jodastephen).

#### `ZonedDateTime` & `Instant`

For each `LocalDate` in our stream, we produce a `ZonedDateTime` object representing the first moment of the day, and another `ZonedDateTime` object for the start of the *following* day. We adjust each of those `ZonedDateTime` moments to be perceived with an offset from UTC of zero hours-minutes-seconds by extracting an `Instant` object.

#### `org.threeten.extra.Interval`

From that pair of `Instant` objects, we produce an `Interval` object. We collect those `Interval` objects in a unmodifiable `List`.

In Java 21+, we can more generally refer to a `List` as a `SequencedCollection`. See [JEP 431](https://openjdk.org/jeps/431).

```java
SequencedCollection < Interval > intervalsOfMonth =
        datesOfMonthStream
                .map( ( LocalDate localDate ) ->
                        Interval.of(
                                localDate.atStartOfDay( zoneId ).toInstant( ) ,
                                localDate.plusDays( 1 ).atStartOfDay( zoneId ).toInstant( )
                        )
                )
                .toList( );
```

Dump to console.

```java
intervalsOfMonth.forEach( System.out :: println );  // Generate text in standard ISO 8601 format.
intervalsOfMonth.forEach( interval -> System.out.println( interval.getStart( ).atZone( zoneId ) + "/" + interval.getEnd( ).atZone( zoneId ) ) );
```

When run:

```
2023-12-31T23:00:00Z/2024-01-01T23:00:00Z
2024-01-01T23:00:00Z/2024-01-02T23:00:00Z
2024-01-02T23:00:00Z/2024-01-03T23:00:00Z
2024-01-03T23:00:00Z/2024-01-04T23:00:00Z
2024-01-04T23:00:00Z/2024-01-05T23:00:00Z
2024-01-05T23:00:00Z/2024-01-06T23:00:00Z
2024-01-06T23:00:00Z/2024-01-07T23:00:00Z
2024-01-07T23:00:00Z/2024-01-08T23:00:00Z
2024-01-08T23:00:00Z/2024-01-09T23:00:00Z
2024-01-09T23:00:00Z/2024-01-10T23:00:00Z
2024-01-10T23:00:00Z/2024-01-11T23:00:00Z
2024-01-11T23:00:00Z/2024-01-12T23:00:00Z
2024-01-12T23:00:00Z/2024-01-13T23:00:00Z
2024-01-13T23:00:00Z/2024-01-14T23:00:00Z
2024-01-14T23:00:00Z/2024-01-15T23:00:00Z
2024-01-15T23:00:00Z/2024-01-16T23:00:00Z
2024-01-16T23:00:00Z/2024-01-17T23:00:00Z
2024-01-17T23:00:00Z/2024-01-18T23:00:00Z
2024-01-18T23:00:00Z/2024-01-19T23:00:00Z
2024-01-19T23:00:00Z/2024-01-20T23:00:00Z
2024-01-20T23:00:00Z/2024-01-21T23:00:00Z
2024-01-21T23:00:00Z/2024-01-22T23:00:00Z
2024-01-22T23:00:00Z/2024-01-23T23:00:00Z
2024-01-23T23:00:00Z/2024-01-24T23:00:00Z
2024-01-24T23:00:00Z/2024-01-25T23:00:00Z
2024-01-25T23:00:00Z/2024-01-26T23:00:00Z
2024-01-26T23:00:00Z/2024-01-27T23:00:00Z
2024-01-27T23:00:00Z/2024-01-28T23:00:00Z
2024-01-28T23:00:00Z/2024-01-29T23:00:00Z
2024-01-29T23:00:00Z/2024-01-30T23:00:00Z
2024-01-30T23:00:00Z/2024-01-31T23:00:00Z
2024-01-01T00:00+01:00[Africa/Tunis]/2024-01-02T00:00+01:00[Africa/Tunis]
2024-01-02T00:00+01:00[Africa/Tunis]/2024-01-03T00:00+01:00[Africa/Tunis]
2024-01-03T00:00+01:00[Africa/Tunis]/2024-01-04T00:00+01:00[Africa/Tunis]
2024-01-04T00:00+01:00[Africa/Tunis]/2024-01-05T00:00+01:00[Africa/Tunis]
2024-01-05T00:00+01:00[Africa/Tunis]/2024-01-06T00:00+01:00[Africa/Tunis]
2024-01-06T00:00+01:00[Africa/Tunis]/2024-01-07T00:00+01:00[Africa/Tunis]
2024-01-07T00:00+01:00[Africa/Tunis]/2024-01-08T00:00+01:00[Africa/Tunis]
2024-01-08T00:00+01:00[Africa/Tunis]/2024-01-09T00:00+01:00[Africa/Tunis]
2024-01-09T00:00+01:00[Africa/Tunis]/2024-01-10T00:00+01:00[Africa/Tunis]
2024-01-10T00:00+01:00[Africa/Tunis]/2024-01-11T00:00+01:00[Africa/Tunis]
2024-01-11T00:00+01:00[Africa/Tunis]/2024-01-12T00:00+01:00[Africa/Tunis]
2024-01-12T00:00+01:00[Africa/Tunis]/2024-01-13T00:00+01:00[Africa/Tunis]
2024-01-13T00:00+01:00[Africa/Tunis]/2024-01-14T00:00+01:00[Africa/Tunis]
2024-01-14T00:00+01:00[Africa/Tunis]/2024-01-15T00:00+01:00[Africa/Tunis]
2024-01-15T00:00+01:00[Africa/Tunis]/2024-01-16T00:00+01:00[Africa/Tunis]
2024-01-16T00:00+01:00[Africa/Tunis]/2024-01-17T00:00+01:00[Africa/Tunis]
2024-01-17T00:00+01:00[Africa/Tunis]/2024-01-18T00:00+01:00[Africa/Tunis]
2024-01-18T00:00+01:00[Africa/Tunis]/2024-01-19T00:00+01:00[Africa/Tunis]
2024-01-19T00:00+01:00[Africa/Tunis]/2024-01-20T00:00+01:00[Africa/Tunis]
2024-01-20T00:00+01:00[Africa/Tunis]/2024-01-21T00:00+01:00[Africa/Tunis]
2024-01-21T00:00+01:00[Africa/Tunis]/2024-01-22T00:00+01:00[Africa/Tunis]
2024-01-22T00:00+01:00[Africa/Tunis]/2024-01-23T00:00+01:00[Africa/Tunis]
2024-01-23T00:00+01:00[Africa/Tunis]/2024-01-24T00:00+01:00[Africa/Tunis]
2024-01-24T00:00+01:00[Africa/Tunis]/2024-01-25T00:00+01:00[Africa/Tunis]
2024-01-25T00:00+01:00[Africa/Tunis]/2024-01-26T00:00+01:00[Africa/Tunis]
2024-01-26T00:00+01:00[Africa/Tunis]/2024-01-27T00:00+01:00[Africa/Tunis]
2024-01-27T00:00+01:00[Africa/Tunis]/2024-01-28T00:00+01:00[Africa/Tunis]
2024-01-28T00:00+01:00[Africa/Tunis]/2024-01-29T00:00+01:00[Africa/Tunis]
2024-01-29T00:00+01:00[Africa/Tunis]/2024-01-30T00:00+01:00[Africa/Tunis]
2024-01-30T00:00+01:00[Africa/Tunis]/2024-01-31T00:00+01:00[Africa/Tunis]
2024-01-31T00:00+01:00[Africa/Tunis]/2024-02-01T00:00+01:00[Africa/Tunis]
```

---

For your copy-paste convenience:

```java
YearMonth yearMonth = YearMonth.of( 2024 , Month.JANUARY );
LocalDate firstOfThatMonth = yearMonth.atDay( 1 );
ZoneId zoneId = ZoneId.of( "Africa/Tunis" );
Stream < LocalDate > datesOfMonthStream = firstOfThatMonth.datesUntil( yearMonth.plusMonths( 1 ).atDay( 1 ) );
SequencedCollection < Interval > intervalsOfMonth =
        datesOfMonthStream
                .map( ( LocalDate localDate ) ->
                        Interval.of(
                                localDate.atStartOfDay( zoneId ).toInstant( ) ,
                                localDate.plusDays( 1 ).atStartOfDay( zoneId ).toInstant( )
                        )
                )
                .toList( );

intervalsOfMonth.forEach( System.out :: println );
intervalsOfMonth.forEach( interval -> System.out.println( interval.getStart( ).atZone( zoneId ) + "/" + interval.getEnd( ).atZone( zoneId ) ) );
```